# Which version of webview of android and ios supports indexeddb?

Tags: cordova, webview, indexeddb

I'm developing a hybrid mobile app using cordova. So I'm researching the solutions for offline storage. It seems indexeddb will be my best choice.

Now I'm not clear which version of webview of each platform support indexed db. I use [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) to check, but I don't think webview of each platform is listed.

Where can I find these information?

Answer (score 6):

I dunno exactly how works cordova. But i think they re directly using the official webview in each OS.

And **caniuse.com actually do list** the support for both android and iOS. It's under *Android Browser* and *iOS Safari*...

[About android, it's made possible because the webviews are no longer using the original (crappy) Android Browser, but a custom chromium build since 4.4:](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#what_version_of_chrome_is_it_based_on_)

- Chromium 30 for 4.4.0
- Chromium 33 for 4.4.3
- Chromium 37 for L Developer preview

(Notice: there could be some strange difference between official chromium support and android browser like [this one](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream), be careful...)

And indexedDb ll be supported in the future iOS 8, it has been annouced during the recent apple keynote.

**To sum up, indexedDB would run on android 4.4+ and iOS8+.**