# Does IndexedDB work with a hybrid android app?

Tags: html, cordova, web-applications, indexeddb, hybrid

I've developed a todo web app using localStorage. However, my new extra functionality, clicking on selected date and getting that day's todo items requires to have a Date object linked to the todo items, so that a specific day's todo items can be retrieved. I'm skeptical about the approach at this point. WebSQL is deprecated but has good support on Android browsers. Since my target app is for an Android browser, WebSQL should work fine. Does IndexedDb work with Android browser? I understand that WebSQL works, but is it future safe to use something that is deprecated? How does Cordova deal with it?

Comment: Maybe duplicate with this 2days old post?
=> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818860/which-version-of-webview-of-android-and-ios-supports-indexeddb/25819046#25819046

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IndexedDb only works on Android 4.4 and up, so if you are also targeting older devices indexedDb isn't enough. 
I use a polyfill for older android devices, see link: https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim

This way I can use the indexedDb support on newer android devices and fall back automatically on the older ones. The fall back uses websql!